# Can we divide layout into two horizontals halves without using TABLELAYOUT

Tags: android-layout

I want to divide the screen into two horizontal halves displaying TEXTVIEW on left and EDITTEXT on right. In total I has 8 rows.. Moreover size of text in each text view varies. Can i do it by using any of the attributes like android:weight or else? I know that i can achieve this by using tableLayout but creating many child layouts affecting the performance. So guys plz suggest any other alternative to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can have two columns and 8 rows keep height of the row as wrap content ,Can you show a layout diagram to understand better and find alternatives

Comment: Thanks Deepak, it seems this can be achieved by using GridLayout. GridLayout avoids creating multiple child layouts and also improves performance of the app.